# Exit program in string functions - upper to lower characters and vice versa

Tags: c

I wanted the two functions to stop the program as the word "exit" is entered, but the loop for that specification is not working. can you please fix this?

Here is the code. please check it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void uppercase(char *str) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=strlen(str); i++) {

        if(str[i]>=65&&str[i]<=90)

            str[i]=str[i]+32;
    }

    printf("\nThe string in lower case is->%s\n",str);
}

void lowercase(char *str) {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<=strlen(str); i++) {

        if(str[i]>=97&&str[i]<=122)

            str[i]=str[i]-32;
    }


    printf("The uppercase equivalent is: %s\n", str);
    getchar();

}

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char lower[100];
    int i;


    while(1)
    {

        printf("Enter any string->");
        scanf("%s",&str);

        if (str == 'exit')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The string is->%s\n",str);

            uppercase(str);

            lowercase(str);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about sharing some code, so we can actually see what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace:

```
if (str == 'exit')
```

by this

```
if (strcmp(str , "exit")==0)
```

Comment: How can I use islower() and isupper() in this program?

Answer (score 0):

```
void uppercase(char *str){
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++){

      //if(islower(str[i]))
         str[i]=toupper(str[i]); 
    }

    printf("\nThe string in uppercase is->%s\n",str);
}
```

Comment: @vonbrand  yes indeed, when developing serious application, one should think to use unicode instead ascii. but in basic things ascii encoding is not that bad.